# posting data with jquery to a class

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post

I'm trying to post some data to a function that will do a mysql insert. Nothing fancy about that. but I can get the thing to work and my question is where should I be telling jQuery to post to and will it honor php includes?

This is what I have

```
include_once 'modules/interviews/helper.php';

if($link == 'my_interviews'){
   include_once 'modules/interviews/my_interviews.php';
} elseif($link == 'interview_panel'){
   include_once 'modules/interviews/interview_panel.php';
}
```

Above is my index.php, which loads in the page where the form is submitted

```
$('.addinote').click(function() {

var app = $(this).attr("data-app"),
user = $(this).attr("data-subi"),
txt = $('#' + app).val();

if(txt === ''){
alert('Whoops, did you enter something?');
}else{
   var  params = {};
   params['user_id'] = user;
   params['app_id'] = app;
   params['inote'] = txt;
   params['subinote'] = '1';

   $.post('http://localhost/gem/modules/interviews/index.php', params,            
       function(data){
           if(data){

           }
           else{
              alert('Whoops, there was a problem, please try again!');
           }
    });
}
```

helper.php contains this...

```
if(isset($_POST['subinote'])){


    $apply->inote();

}
```

and the class contains this....

```
function inote(){

$query = "INSERT INTO `app_notes` (`user_id`, `application_id`, `inote`) 
          VALUES ('{$_POST['user_id']}', '{$_POST['app_id']}', 
          '{$_POST['inote']}')";    

$GLOBALS['DB']->insertQuery($query);

}
```

Where should I be posting to?

Comment: On a point of clarify, jQuery has no implications on whether includes will be honoured. jQuery is the client, your includes are the server - they are completely separate, disparate environments. jQuery has no knowledge of what on the server will handle what it's sending. In other words, yes, your includes will work just fine regardless as to whether they are fed jQuery or by some other means.

Comment: Thanks that's great to know that the includes will run thank you! I hate troubleshooting javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be posting to index.php if this is the one reading the $_POST variable.

Also you should be using relative url's for example if helper.php is in the same directory as your html file use `./index.php` or simply `index.php` as your post url.  I prefer the former as it states explicitly what you intended.

Comment: Sorry i typed helper when I meant index lol, edited my post now to correct this.

Comment: can I do something like this? /index.php?link=apps to make sure the very highest level is included?

Comment: yeah this will point at your web root directory, you realise that you are passing get parameters in your post request by adding the `?link=apps` part on the end?  I'm not sure how this is handeled, im guessing you may be able to pass both get and post parameters but im not sure, I don't really know too much about that side of things.

Comment: Yeah it seems to work, using a get request in the post url doesn't seem to matter. Thanks for your help!